# PHP / SQL Query and PHP Variables

Tags: php, sql

I have this query below:

```
$msgg = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE time>$time
AND id='someid'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT $display_num",$myconn);
```

see this line: **AND id='someid' <-- someid ...**

OK, the query above returns 2 results as expected...

Now for the problem....

-- I have a variable myVar and it's content is "**someid**" (without quotes)...same as the string '**someid**'

When I do this:

```
$msgg = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE time>$time
AND id=myVar
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT $display_num",$myconn);
```

*See: myVar <-- this variable contans .. someid*

The second query returns no results.

*Update:* When using `... AND id='$myVar'`  it sees `$myVar` as empty for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a $ in front of myVar:

```
$msgg = mysql_query(
"SELECT *
   FROM mytable
  WHERE time > $time
    AND id   = '$myVar'
  ORDER BY id ASC
  LIMIT $display_num", $myconn
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dollar sign and the single quotations:

```
AND id='$myVar'
```

Additionally, you may want to consider using [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$query = <<<MYSQL
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE time>$time
AND id='$myVar'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT $display_num
MYSQL;

$msgg = mysql_query($query, $myconn);
```