# PHP variables in SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

This is part of my code:

```
$sql = "select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = $uid;";
    $c = new dbConnect();
    $results = pg_query($c->pgConnect(), $sql);
    if (!$results)
    {
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    }
```

When I execute it from SSH, the following message appears:

```
LINE 1: select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = ;
```

It appears as if `$uid` isn't being injected properly, but I'm not sure why. I also tried `pg_prepare`, with the same result. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Where have you defined `$uid`

Comment: Does your `$uid` variable have a value?

Comment: how do you get that uid value? maybe it is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP / SQL Query and PHP Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263524/php-sql-query-and-php-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = '" . $uid . "'";
```

And make sure that `$uid` exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = '" . (int)$uid . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf("select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = '%s'", 
$uid); 
// Then run the query. 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score -2):

The Variable is obviously empty. Also it's always good to not mixing up strings and variables

```
$sql = "select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = " . $uid . ";";
```

If `$uid` is supposed to be a string rather than an integer, wrap it with quotes:

```
$sql = "select uid,connected,callerid2 from calls where uid = '" . $uid . "';";
```